# What equipment do I need to transplant a 20' tall pin oak?

Tags: trees, transplanting, technique, tools, oak

I knew a guy who moved 7 or 8 large (for moving) 20-35' [pin oaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercus_palustris). He used a backhoe, digging out around the rootball, while leaving it intact. While this was successful, and the trees did very well, it completely wrecked all the surrounding land.

I know it's not ideal to move trees this size, but if I do, is there a less aggressive method, and what tools should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lancelot "Capability" Brown](http://www.comptonverney.org.uk/_userfiles/pages/file/Exhibitions/Capability_Brown_gallery_guide.pdf)  who was born in 1716 invented this machine.  Sometimes the root ball was so heavy he had labourers perch in the foliage to counter balance it while moving.  You might be able to pay for the equipment by giving rides!

[image: tree mover]